# Can't execute transaction with isolation = serializable correctly in Spring boot (postgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, transactions, isolation-level

I have a spring boot application and postgreSQL database. I want to make a transaction with isolation of SERIALIZABLE or REPEATABLE_READ. The goal is update a specific entity called product given an id and garantee while the transaction is running, others cannot read/update/delete the entity.

I develop the code bellow to test the @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE) for this example. I put a sleep thread between the **findById (SELECT)** and **save (UPDATE)** (both defined by JpaRepository), to run two simultaneous transactions, updating the same product, spaced 5 seconds apart.

```
@Autowired
private IQueryProductRepository queryProductRepository;

@Autowired
private ICommandProductRepository commandProductRepository;    

@Override
public ResponseEntity updateProduct(String id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(update(id, "name changed"));
}

@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public Product update(String id, String name){
    Optional<Product> optional = queryProductRepository.findById(id);
    Product product = optional.get();
    System.err.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " - SLEEP");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.err.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " - WAKE");
    product.setName(name);
    product = commandProductRepository.save(product);
    return product;
}

**Output:** 
2021-07-15T20:44:33.584670570 - SLEEP
2021-07-15T20:44:41.377932607 - SLEEP
2021-07-15T20:44:53.585632949 - WAKE
2021-07-15T20:45:01.378063371 - WAKE
```

It would be expected that the first transaction locks the product entity and the second transaction would only be able to update when the first transaction ends. But the result was not that, when I execute the first transaction, "SLEEP" is printed and it enters the sleep thread and when I execute the second transaction, 5 seconds after the first transaction, the "SLEEP" is immediately printed, which means that the second transaction got access to the entity, while the first has not yet ended.

I don't understand why this occur, since I put isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE?

My application properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cc
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how the SERIALIZABLE isolation level works. What you are describing is more or less a single user system. The idea behind the SERIALIZABLE isolation level is that it still allows concurrency, but ensures that concurrent transactions do not interfere with each other. One transaction might fail if the overlapping of multiple transactions is not SERIALIZABLE i.e. doesn't provide the guarantees of preventing phantom reads. This is just a layman explanation, but if you want a single user execution, you will need some kind of pessimistic lock on a shared object.